# Search box within a div CSS

Tags: html, css, forms

I'm working on the CSS for a youtube api search page. I have a search box inside of a wrapper div that I want to take up no more than 100% the width of the parent div. However, the search box goes outside of the div by a few pixels. I used the box-sizing track I have seen on css tricks but that hasn't solved this styling issue. I'm sure I am forgetting something silly so I need another brain to help.

Here is my project on github: http://amalthea5.github.io/thinkful-tube/

Edit: Thanks to both of you who answered you've solved my woes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `padding` on parent element instead of `margin` on `input` and use `box-sizing: border-box` property.

```
label {
    display: block; 
    padding: .5em;
}

#query {
    display: block; 
    width: 100%; 
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    margin: 0;
}
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jcLgzcg1/

Answer (score 0):

Add padding left and right for 
`.buttons {   padding-left: 2em; padding-right: 2em;}`

you don't need to set margin-left and margin-right for #query

Here is updated css

```
.buttons { 
     text-align: center; 
     padding: 2em; 
     max-width: 900px; 
}
#query { 
    display: block; 
    border: 1px solid #000; 
    width: 100%; 
    font-size: 1.5em; 
    margin-bottom: 1em; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what happens here is `#query` uses a margin left and margin right which forces your input box to move out of focus. A simple fix would be to update the following css classes accordingly. Fix provide by me removed the unwanted margins and instead provides to the parent wrapper of buttons.

```
.buttons {
    max-width: 900px;
    padding: 2em;
    text-align: center;
}

#query {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    width: 100%;
}
```